# How does a metal atom's size affect the electrical conductivity of it's giant metallic structure?

Tags: metal, conductivity, electricity

In giant metallic structures, how does a metal atom's size affect the structure's electrical conductivity? (i.e. what happens if you go down a group of metal elements?)

Comment: Why do you think sole size would be important?

Comment: @Mithoron: I don't. That's why I'm asking about it's effects on conductivity.